# I need to show that graph of $f(x)=x^2$ is a topological manifold

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

I started proving considering $\gamma = \{(x,x^2):x\in \mathbb{R}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and I proved till II countable now Iam stuck in showing the map $\omega:\gamma \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\omega(x,x^2)=x$ is homeomorphic I got till onto but struggling to prove the inverse map is continuous

Comment: What is the image of your graph by the homeomorphism $(x,y)\to (x,y-f(x))$ ?

Comment: The inverse map is the (restriction of the) projection map onto the first coordinate.

Comment: To be clear, it most certainly IS a topological manifold (a smooth manifold, even).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph of a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a topological manifold homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$.  If $G\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ is the graph of $f$, then the projection $(x,f(x))\mapsto x$ is a homeomorphism.

The projection $(x,f(x))\mapsto x$ is continuous (independent of the nature of $f$), and $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ is also continuous (because $f$ is continuous).

More generally (concerning the product topology):

- the projections $\pi_X, \pi_Y$ from $X\times Y$ to the factors are always continuous,
- $z\mapsto (f(z), g(z))\in X\times Y$ is continuous iff each of $f$ and $g$ are continuous (iff composing with the projections is continuous).